# How does Haskell "desugar" getline in this do block?

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

I've read a few books on Haskell but haven't coded in it all that much, and I'm a little confused as to what Haskell is doing in a certain case. Let's say I'm using `getLine` so the user can push a key to continue, but I don't really want to interpret that person's input in any meaningful way. I believe this is a valid way of doing this:

```
main = do
    _ <- getLine
    putStrLn "foo"
```

I understand the basic gist of what's this is doing. `getLine` returns an `IO String`, and `putStrLn` takes a `String` and returns `IO ()`, so if I theoretically wanted to print what the user typed into the console, I'd basically utilize the `>>=` operator from the `Monad` class. In my case, I believe my code is equivalent to `getLine >> putStrLn "foo"` since I'm discarding the return value of `getLine`.

However, what if I do this instead?

```
main = do
    let _ = getLine
    putStrLn "foo"
```

In this case, we're setting up a sort of lambda to work with something that will take an `IO String`, right? I could write a `printIOString` function to print the user's input and that would work fine. When I'm not actually using that `IO String`, though, the program behaves strangely... `getLine` doesn't even prompt me for input; the program just prints out `"foo"`.

I'm not really sure what the "desugared" syntax would be here, or if that would shed some light on what Haskell is doing under the hood.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's warm up with a few more complicated examples.

```
main = do
    x
    x
    x
    putStrLn "foo"
    where
    x = do
        getLine
```

What do you expect this to do? I don't know about you, but what *I* expect is for the program to get three lines and then print something. If we desugar the second `do` block, we get

```
main = do
    x
    x
    x
    putStrLn "foo"
    where x = getLine
```

Since this is the desugaring of the other one, it behaves the same, getting three lines before printing. There's another line of thought that arrives at the same answer, if you don't find this first one intuitive. "Referential transparency", one of the defining features of Haskell, means exactly that you can replace a "reference" to something (that is, a variable name) with its definition, so the previous program should be exactly the same program as

```
main = do
    getLine
    getLine
    getLine
    putStrLn "foo"
```

if we are taking the equation `x = getLine` seriously. Okay, so we have a program that reads three lines and prints. What about this one?

```
main = do
    x
    x
    putStrLn "foo"
    where x = getLine
```

Get two lines and print. And this one?

```
main = do
    x
    putStrLn "foo"
    where x = getLine
```

Get one line and then print. Hopefully you see where this is going...

```
main = do
    putStrLn "foo"
    where x = getLine
```

Get zero lines and then print, i.e. just print immediately! I used `where` instead of `let` to make the opening example a bit more obvious, but you can pretty much always replace a `where` block with its `let` cousin without changing its meaning:

```
main = let x = getLine in do
    putStrLn "foo"
```

Since we don't refer to `x`, we don't even need to name it:

```
main = let _ = getLine in do
    putStrLn "foo"
```

and this is the desugaring of the code you wrote.

Comment: Wow, great approach to explanation!

Comment: Thanks! It makes so much sense now. :)

Answer (score 4):

The first case is desugared like you expected:

```
main = getLine >>= \_ -> putStrLn "foo"
```

which is equivalent to

```
main = getLine >> putStrLn "foo"
```

In the second case,

```
main = do
    let _ = getLine
    putStrLn "foo"
```

is desugared as

```
main = let _ = getLine in putStrLn "foo"
```

Since the `_ = getLine` value is not needed to evaluate the RHS of the `let` expression, the compiler is free to ignore it and the IO effect is never executed, which is why you're not prompted for CLI input anymore.

Even though both cases ignored the result of `getLine` the difference is that the first case evaluates `getLine` in an `IO` context while the second case evaluates `getLine` as a pure value. In `IO` the side-effects must executed and sequenced together, but in a pure context the compiler is free to ignore unused values.

I wouldn't recommend doing this as it's not very idiomatic, but you could write something like

```
printIOString :: IO String -> IO ()
printIOString ios = ios >>= putStrLn
```

and use it like `printIOString getLine`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info,

```
do { let { _ = getLine } ; putStrLn "foo" } 
= 
do { let { _ = getLine } in putStrLn "foo" } 
= 
     let { _ = getLine } in putStrLn "foo"
```

which by Haskell semantics is equivalent to

```
    getLine & (\ _ -> putStrLn "foo")
=
                      putStrLn "foo"
```

(with `x & f = f x`), whereas indeed

```
do { _ <- getLine ; putStrLn "foo" }
=
  getLine >>= (\ _ -> putStrLn "foo")
```

which can't be further simplified.